# How can i make SmartSVN to ignore files .o and .obj

Tags: svn, smartsvn

don't understand how to make SmartSVN to ignores files of different type (like .o and .obj)
I've tried to go Project -> Default Settings -> Global Ignores -> Use following patterns :

```
*.o
*.obj
*.d
```

But they are still getting versioned and shown
Does anyone knows what's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `svn:ignore` property or adding ignore pattern any other way in Subversion does not affect any files that are already versioned. I.e., ignore pattern applies only to data that is not versioned. You need to unversion the file which you want to be ignored by Subversion.  [SVNBook](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) says:

> Subversion's support for ignorable file patterns extends only to the
> one-time process of adding unversioned files and directories to
> version control. Once an object is under Subversion's control, the
> ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it. In other words, don't
> expect Subversion to avoid committing changes you've made to a
> versioned file simply because that file's name matches an ignore
> pattern—Subversion always notices all of its versioned objects.